# How can I force a window full screen in python (using easyGUI)

Tags: python, fullscreen, easygui

I am just starting out using easyGUI with Python, and am running in to a bit of trouble. I want my application to run in full screen. However, I can not figure out how to get this to work.

This could apply to any python/easyGUI code, such as something as simple as hello world:

```
from easygui import *
msgbox("Hello, world!")
```

Your advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/), as none of the [methods](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/download/version0.95/pydoc/easygui.html) even allow for width and height arguments; you're sacrificing extensibility for ease of use.

This can be done with Tkinter directly.  Here's a nice example for [Making a Toplevel cover the Full Screen](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-toplevel-fullscreen.htm).